# Elasticsearch client.indices().putTemplate - Deprecated Method

Tags: java, elasticsearch, intellij-idea, groovy, deprecated

From the [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.13/java-rest-high-put-template.html#java-rest-high-put-template-sync) there is a line which says:

```
AcknowledgedResponse putTemplateResponse = client.indices().putTemplate(request, LEGACY_TEMPLATE_OPTIONS);
```

Unfortunately, there are two methods in the Javadoc with the same signature. [A deprecated one](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/7.5.1/org/elasticsearch/client/IndicesClient.html#putTemplate(org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.template.put.PutIndexTemplateRequest,org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions)) and [a newer one](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/7.5.1/org/elasticsearch/client/IndicesClient.html#putTemplate(org.elasticsearch.client.indices.PutIndexTemplateRequest,org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions)). In IntelliJ-idea it always refers to the deprecated one. I don't know how to fix this.

This is the way how I use it in the code:

```
AcknowledgedResponse putTemplateResponse = client.indices().putTemplate(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
org.elasticsearch.client.core.AcknowledgedResponse putTemplateResponse = client.indices().putTemplate(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

When creating your object.

Comment: It was actually the request. I used  `org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.template.put.PutIndexTemplateRequest`
instead of the correct one: `org.elasticsearch.client.indices.PutIndexTemplateRequest`

Comment: @boraas It's totally fine to create your own answer for your problem